# How to validate only visible elements of a form?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have three input fields `#product_upc`, `#product_price` and `#product_quantity`, they are in the same place. I have a checkbox `#to_hide` and when users check it, the three inputs goes hidden(using `hide()` method). If the user uncheck the checkbox the three inputs become visible again, this time using `show()` method (I could use use `toggle()` instead but prefer to use this approach).

Now, when I submit the form I need to verify if those three input are visible and if they are visible then validate that they are not empty and in case of `#product_upc` I should check UPC validity by calling `checkUPC(param)` function.

I made this code but it's not working since elements are `visible` and code never pass trough validation:

```
if (($("#product_upc").val() !== '' || $("#product_upc").val().length >= 0) && $("#product_upc").is(":visible")) {
    if (checkUPC($("#product_upc").val()) === false) {
        alert("El UPC es inválido");
        valid = false;
        return false;
    }
}

if ($("#product_price").is(":visible")) {
    if (!$.trim($("#product_price")).length) {
        alert("Debes escribir un precio");
        valid = false;
        $(this).focus();
        return false;
    }
}
if ($("#product_quantity").is(":visible")) {
    if (!$.trim($("#product_quantity")).length) {
        alert("Debes escribir una cantidad");
        valid = false;
        $(this).focus();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Which mistake I made?

Comment: How can your user click on a invisible element?

Comment: @ClaudioSantos users don't click in a invisible element, they mark a checkbox and if the checkbox is marked then fields are hide, if checkbox is unmarked fields go back

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: @ManikandanSigamani none, just validation never happen since I don't get any alert saying fields are empty and placing focus on the field which make the issue

Comment: It doesn't even enter the isvisible if condition?

Comment: @ManikandanSigamani yes, those are triggered just don't know why the other part fails

Comment: can you pls check in the browser developer tools, the value for this? !$.trim($("#product_price")).length

Comment: @ManikandanSigamani I changed to this notation `$("#product_price").val().length === 0` and it works now

Comment: @Reynier you're joining the data with the view, your view(html code) need to create a json element, so this element must be validate, if you keep validate your data through the view you'll still having problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Fixed II:**
So, you want to check if a html element is visible or not, you first need to use `hide()` or `show()`, then you can use `$('.panel1').is(':visible')` to check if an element is visible or not. Take a look [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/csantos/Wnu88/).

**Fixed:**
Please take a look at [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/csantos/Wnu88/1/) code at fiddle.

I developed a validation function that was called only if a div are visible.

---

You could use two classes for this field, and associate the event only for visible class.

```
Out Field<input type="text" /> </br>
<div class="panel1">
    Field 1 <input type="text" /> </br>
    Field 2 <input type="text" /> </br>
    Field 3 <input type="text" /> </br>
</div>
<input type="checkbox" class="visible" checked=true>Visible</input></br>
<input type="button" class="btnValidate" value="Validate"></input>
```

After user click you could change this class to invisibleCheckBox

Then you associate the event to the class:

```
$('.visible').click(function(){
    if ($(this).prop('checked')){
        $('.panel1').show();
    }else{
        $('.panel1').hide();
    }

});

$('.btnValidate').click(function(){

    if ($('.panel1').is(':visible')) 
        alert('works');

    if ($(".visible").prop('checked')){
        console.log('validate!');
    }else{
        console.log('dont validate!');
    }    
});
```

Comment: Take a look at the edition I made trying to clarify a bit the post

Comment: Please @Reynier take a look now, cause a made some fixs.